# MS Access: ConcatRelated function works with source table but not with query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, concatenation, ms-access-2013

I use ConcatRelated function (made by [Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)) to merge string values from several rows in the MainTable, grouped by CategoryNumber:

```
ConcatRelated("[TextField]", "[MainTable]", "[CategoryNumber] = " & [CategoryNumber])
```

In that scenario, function works perfectly. However, I need to merge rows with only some of the categories. I store these selected categories in the Table2. I made Query1 that connects Table2 with MainTable through Tag field.

```
SELECT MainTable.CategoryNumber, MainTable.TextField
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN MainTable ON Table2.Tag = MainTable.ConnectedTag;
```

Now I have only selected rows I want to use with Concat function. I try to use it in the same way as previous:

```
ConcatRelated("[TextField]", "[Query1]", "[CategoryNumber] = " & [CategoryNumber])
```

Then occurs **Error 3061: too few parameters. Expected 1.**

I also try to use Concat as the event procedure in the form. 
In result i see **Run-time error '2465' can't find the field '|1'**

ConcatRelated module looks like this and, as mentioned before, it works just fine in many other cases:

```
Public Function ConcatRelated(strField As String, _
strTable As String, _
Optional strWhere As String, _
Optional strOrderBy As String, _
Optional strSeparator = ", ") As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsMV As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String 
Dim strOut As String
Dim lngLen As Long
Dim bIsMultiValue As Boolean

ConcatRelated = Null

strSQL = "SELECT " & strField & " FROM " & strTable
If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strWhere
End If
If strOrderBy <> vbNullString Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY " & strOrderBy
End If
Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

bIsMultiValue = (rs(0).Type > 100)

Do While Not rs.EOF
    If bIsMultiValue Then
        'For multi-valued field, loop through the values
        Set rsMV = rs(0).Value
        Do While Not rsMV.EOF
            If Not IsNull(rsMV(0)) Then
                strOut = strOut & rsMV(0) & strSeparator
            End If
            rsMV.MoveNext
        Loop
        Set rsMV = Nothing
    ElseIf Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
        strOut = strOut & rs(0) & strSeparator
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close

lngLen = Len(strOut) - Len(strSeparator)
If lngLen > 0 Then
    ConcatRelated = Left(strOut, lngLen)
End If

Exit_Handler:
Set rsMV = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Exit Function

Err_Handler:
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ConcatRelated()"
Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

I use Access 2013 with SQL server. What I do wrong?

Comment: You might want to mention the source and author of ConcatRelated. Posting code that isn't written by you on Stack Overflow without disclosing the author is considered plagiarism.

Comment: The author is mentioned in the very first sentence of my post. His name is Allen Browne and everyone who tried concat their data in the Access probably know the one and only Allen Browne. Is he enough mentioned now?

Comment: You still haven't mentioned the source, just the author...

Comment: Ok, i have placed url. I belive that Allen who has droped Access ages ago for finding Jesus will forgive me. You might want to answer my question now.

Comment: "You might want to answer my question now" lol classic.....

Comment: Well, I probably would if I could reproduce the issue. Start by providing a reproducible example.

Comment: If it was reproducible with the information you've provided, I wouldn't ask for a reproducible example. I'm trying to get you to ask a good question, with a reproducible example, so I can help you. You just rant and don't take my advice. That doesn't go over well on this site

Comment: Oh, so let's see how it works on this site then. First, you came out with the false accusation and you call me fraud just because you didn't notice that I pay credits to the author. When you realised that, you didn't apologize but asked for url to author's page, which is completely irrelevant since you have a code, authors name and google. After you get everything you needed, you are still rude and still you have not come out with any hypothesis. So forgive me, but i think you just waste my time and I will not beg you for your help. Just go somwhere else, please :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, can't use ConcatRelated in the same query the function references. Reference [MainTable] even when function called in Query1.

Comment: Or build Query2 with the function call that references Query1.

Comment: @June7, thank you for your answer. It gave me an idea to use concat with temporary table instead of query.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. ConcatRelated doesn't want to read my query, so I decided to feed function with temporary table, where I will put data from that query. Here is the example workaround:

**Build temporary table:**

1. Create table with the same structure as your query.
2. Change your query type to Append Query (don't use Concat function yet - you will build another query for that).
3. Set where each column of your Append Query should send data to your temporary table.

**Make sure your temporary table has accurate data:**

4. If you use ConcatRelated in specific form, add VBA to this form's opening event to delete all records from temporary table (something like this:

   DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM TempTable;")
5. Now your temp table is clear, so you may execute your Append Query (in the same form’s event procedure), to fulfill temp table with proper data:

   DoCmd.OpenQuery "YourAppendQuery"
6. Run another query (the one with ConcatRealted function), but this time refer to your temp table. In above case, it would look like that:

   ConcatRelated("[TextField]", "[TempTable]", "[CategoryNumber] = " & [CategoryNumber])

Maybe it's not a beautiful solution, but it works for me and allows me to go further with my project.